# how can I let crunchbang use my wlan board?

Tags: wifi-driver, crunchbang

I recently put #!, a linux distro based on Debian, on my computer. All the installation process was OK, but finally, when I switched it on, I saw there wasn't written anything about the WiFi connection in the bar. So I ran:

```
iwconfig
ifconfig
```

And I got the following results:

> shoyip@shoichi-crunchbang:~$ iwconfig
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>   eth0      no wireless extensions.
>   pan0      no wireless extensions.
>
> shoyip@shoichi-crunchbang:~$ ifconfig
>   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr e8:9a:8f:68:a6:d2  
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>             Interrupt:29 Base address:0x2000
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:5184 (5.0 KiB)  TX bytes:5184 (5.0 KiB)
>
> shoyip@shoichi-crunchbang:~$ lspci 00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro
>   Devices [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro
>   Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx) 00:05.0 PCI bridge:
>   Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
>   00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 SATA
>   Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40) 00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI
>   Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller 00:12.2 USB
>   Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
>   00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0
>   Controller 00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800
>   USB EHCI Controller 00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus
>   Controller (rev 42) 00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00
>   Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40) 00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc
>   SB700/SB800 LPC host controller (rev 40) 00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI
>   Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40) 00:14.5 USB
>   Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI2 Controller
>   00:15.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 43a0 00:15.1 PCI
>   bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 43a1 00:15.2 PCI bridge: ATI
>   Technologies Inc Device 43a2 00:15.3 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc
>   Device 43a3 00:16.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800
>   USB OHCI0 Controller 00:16.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc
>   SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller 00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro
>   Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
>   00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor
>   Address Map 00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family
>   10h Processor DRAM Controller 00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro
>   Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control 00:18.4 Host
>   bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
>   01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M880G
>   [Mobility Radeon HD 4200] 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek
>   Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
>   controller (rev 06) 04:00.0 Network controller: RaLink Device 5390
>   shoyip@shoichi-crunchbang:~$ lsmod | grep rt2860sta
>   shoyip@shoichi-crunchbang:~$

I followed [these](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-auf-asus-a73s-laptop-einrichten/#post-2960487) instructions, then [these](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2860sta)(I used Google Translate to understand it), but still no WiFi connection. What i have to do? Thanks in advance, Sho.

Comment: Could you please tell us some more about what you actually did? Also, please post the output of the commands you ran. What is your hardware? The 2nd link you gave (the first is in German which I do not speak) is about a specific chipset, is that what your card has?

Comment: I've installed crunchbang on my computer, but it doesn't detect my wlan adapter. Running lspci I get 04:00.0 Network controller: RaLink Device 5390, so I am quite sure that it's talking about my card. Iwconfig: lo no wireless extension eth0 no wireless extension pan0 no wireless extension. Ifconfig: Seth0 link encap: Ethernet hwaddr e8:9a:8f:68:a6:d2 UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets... lo Link encap:local loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0

Comment: Please update your question with the output of these commands, it makes it much easier to understand. Ideally, we would like to see each command you have run. Giving a link to instructions in a different language that you claim to have followed is not very helpful. Also, please post the output of `lsmod | grep rt2860sta`.

Comment: OK, I will switch on #!, then I'll post the outputs.